Crash Expo 52: Please ensure that you do not access the `value` property or use `get` method of a shared value while React is rendering a component
After I upgraded to Expo 52 the react-native-reanimated is printing me error and crashing.
This is the full error code

(NOBRIDGE) WARN  [Reanimated] Reading from value during component render. Please ensure that you do not access the value property or use get method of a shared value while React is rendering a component.

This is my package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.4",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^5.0.5",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.31",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "axios": "^1.7.4",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "expo": "^52.0.7",
    "expo-blur": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-file-system": "^18.0.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-secure-store": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.5",
    "react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~4.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "15.8.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3",
    "yup": "^1.3.3",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.13",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~4.0.0"
  }

I commented everywhere where I have used react-native-reanimated, and no crash occurred.
This is an example where I have used the library
    import Animated, {
      Extrapolate,
      interpolate,
      runOnJS,
      useAnimatedStyle,
      useSharedValue,
    } from "react-native-reanimated";
    
    
    import React from "react";
    import { View } from "react-native";
    import Animated, {
      Extrapolate,
      interpolate,
      runOnJS,
      useAnimatedStyle,
      useSharedValue,
    } from "react-native-reanimated";
    import Carousel from "react-native-reanimated-carousel";
    import CarCardComponent from "../features/home/components/CarCardComponent";
    import { window } from "../features/favourites/constants";
    import { primaryColor } from "../types/colors";
    
    const PAGE_WIDTH = window.width;
    
    function CardsCarousel({
      vehicles,
      navigateToVehicleInformation,
    }: {
      vehicles: any[];
      navigateToVehicleInformation: any;
    }) {
      const [isVertical] = React.useState(false);
      const [autoPlay] = React.useState(false);
      const [pagingEnabled] = React.useState(true);
      const [snapEnabled] = React.useState(true);
      const progressValue = useSharedValue(0);
    
      const baseOptions = isVertical
        ? {
            vertical: true,
            width: PAGE_WIDTH,
            height: PAGE_WIDTH * 0.8,
          }
        : {
            vertical: false,
            width: PAGE_WIDTH,
            height: 380,
          };
    
      const modeConfig = {
        parallaxScrollingScale: 0.9,
        parallaxScrollingOffset: isVertical ? 50 : 60,
      };
    
      const getPaginationItems = () => {
        if (!vehicles || vehicles.length === 0) {
          return null;
        }
    
        return vehicles.map((_, index) => (
          <PaginationItem
            backgroundColor={primaryColor}
            animValue={progressValue}
            index={index}
            key={index}
            isRotate={isVertical}
            length={vehicles.length}
          />
        ));
      };
    
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            alignItems: "center",
            marginHorizontal: 10,
          }}
        >
          {vehicles && vehicles.length > 0 && (
            <Carousel
              {...baseOptions}
              style={{ width: PAGE_WIDTH }}
              loop
              pagingEnabled={pagingEnabled}
              snapEnabled={snapEnabled}
              autoPlay={autoPlay}
              autoPlayInterval={1500}
              onProgressChange={(_, absoluteProgress) => {
                runOnJS(() => {
                  progressValue.value = absoluteProgress;
                })();
              }}
              mode="parallax"
              modeConfig={modeConfig}
              data={vehicles}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <CarCardComponent
                  car={item}
                  navigateToVehicleInformation={navigateToVehicleInformation}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
          {!!progressValue && vehicles && vehicles.length > 0 && (
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: isVertical ? "column" : "row",
                alignItems: "center",
                marginTop: 10,
              }}
            >
              {getPaginationItems()}
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    const PaginationItem: React.FC<{
      index: number;
      backgroundColor: string;
      length: number;
      animValue: Animated.SharedValue<number>;
      isRotate?: boolean;
    }> = (props) => {
      const { animValue, index, length, backgroundColor, isRotate } = props;
      const width = 10;
    
      const animStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        let inputRange = [index - 1, index, index + 1];
        let outputRange = [-width, 0, width];
    
        if (index === 0 && animValue?.value > length - 1) {
          inputRange = [length - 1, length, length + 1];
          outputRange = [-width, 0, width];
        }
    
        return {
          transform: [
            {
              translateX: interpolate(
                animValue?.value,
                inputRange,
                outputRange,
                Extrapolate.CLAMP
              ),
            },
          ],
        };
      }, [animValue, index, length]);
    
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "white",
            width,
            height: width,
            borderRadius: 50,
            overflow: "hidden",
            marginHorizontal: 4,
            transform: [
              {
                rotateZ: isRotate ? "90deg" : "0deg",
              },
            ],
          }}
        >
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              {
                borderRadius: 50,
                backgroundColor,
                flex: 1,
              },
              animStyle,
            ]}
          />
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default CardsCarousel;

Before upgrading to Expo 52, everything worked perfectly fine, i also run expo docker to match all dependencies with the SDK version but still no luck.

This is how I fix it:

In package.json  change to "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "4.0.0-canary.17"

rm -rf node_modules

npm i // to install the new version

In node_modules/react-native-reanimated-carousel/src/layouts/parallax.ts
you have to change the zIndex (line 55) constant with:


const zIndex = Math.round(
      interpolate(
        value,
        [-1, 0, 1],
        [0, size, 0],
        Extrapolation.CLAMP,
      )
    );

This is a TEMPORARY fix in order to the team fix the code :D
hope this help.

Thank you for your comment, but I think that altering the files inside node_modules will not be an optimal solution.

I know is just a temporary fix

This worked and is an absolute life saver in the short term. I also didn't have to add the 4.0.0-canary.17. In my opinion, that version should already have the fix. Until they publish the fix, I'd stick to using this. Thanks a lot!
